# How to get list of recently created AD users from azure active directory using Azure CLI

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I need the list of recently created AD users from azure active directory using Azure CLI

I need the users which is created in AD in the past 2 hours/24 hours. Is it possible to get it via CLI Command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like the following:

```
az ad user list --filter "createdDateTime ge datetime'2020-06-10'"
```

This will list the users created on or after 10th June 2020.

Comment: Thanks for update, is there a way I can filter a group first and then list the users created on that group recently

Comment: I am not sure. I tried following: `az ad group member list -g "<group-name>" --filter "createdDateTime ge datetime'2020-06-10'"` but that didn't work. You may want to look into it.

Comment: Can i get for last 2 hours instead of 24 hours  ?   (az ad user list --filter "createdDateTime ge datetime'2020-06-10'")

Comment: You could calculate the UTC date time - 2 hours and specify filter as `"createdDateTime ge datetime'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ'"`.

Comment: thanks ..it helped .... it means that if use that date format after calculated utc - 2 hours ... it will give me the output of the last 2 hours right ?

Answer (score 0):

The powershell version is almost the same.  The filter is picky with the date string format:

```
get-azureaduser -filter "createddatetime ge datetime'2020-06-10'"
```