# Is it possible to query Azure Active Directory users based on last modified date?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I need to get a users from Azure Active directory who were created/modified since a specific date.
Is this possible, via graph or any other means?

I have checked the graph api documentation but cannot see a lastModified filter.

Comment: There‘s only createdDateTime in user property.https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSk3H.png

Answer (score 1):

**There is no such property called `lastModifiedDateTime` in Microsoft Graph.**

As [**@Tiny Wang**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15581227/tiny-wang) suggested, you can query using **`createdDateTime`**.

***From **Azure CLI**, to get Azure AD users created since a specific date, make use of below command:***

```
az ad user list --filter "createdDateTime ge datetime'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ'"
```

***From **Microsoft Graph API**, to get Azure AD users created since a specific date, make use of below command:***

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=createdDateTime ge yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ &$select=displayName,createdDateTime,id
```

[image]

Before using the above command, make sure to give the below **permissions**:

[image]

**References:**

[How to get list of recently created AD users from azure active directory using Azure CLI - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62322512/how-to-get-list-of-recently-created-ad-users-from-azure-active-directory-using-a)

[Microsoft Graph User last modified field - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63260565/microsoft-graph-user-last-modified-field)

[Get a user - Microsoft Graph beta | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http)

Comment: Thanks for this. Created date is not useful in this case as other attributes of a user change on a periodic basis, which is why I need to identify users who have changed/been modified since a specific date. Does this mean there is no way to identify users who have had a change since a specific date?

Comment: Hi @wilson_smyth ! As I already mentioned, `lastmodifieddatetime` property is not there. But if that change is somewhat related to **lastSignInDateTime** , you can make use of this **[Graph API query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#example-5-list-the-last-sign-in-time-of-users-in-a-specific-time-range)** where you can get list of last signed-in users in specific time range

Comment: just a detail in the az command (I wasn't able to edit the answer). The command should be az ad user list --filter "createdDateTime ge datetime'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ'" without space after datetime.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment there is no `modifiedDateTime` or similar property on `User` resource type.

If you want to filter users who were created since a specific date then you can use `createdDateTime` property.

Example to get users created since 01/01/2022

```
GET /users?$filter=createdDateTime ge 2022-01-01T00:00:00Z
```

Example to get users created in 2021

```
GET /users?$filter=(createdDateTime ge 2021-01-01T00:00:00Z AND createdDateTime le 2021-12-31T23:59:59Z)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Created date is not useful in this case as other attributes of a user change on a periodic basis. Does this mean there is no way to identify users who have had a change since a specific date?

Comment: you need to use delta's to see what changed but no field for last modified as far as I know