# Extract last modified uses from Azure AD using API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have an requirement to extract all the users from Azure AD based on last modified date and I have tried with graph API https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users but seem its only give full user not based on the last modified.

Is there any alternative approach I can use ? Please help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please note that, there is no property named **`lastmodifieddatetime`** in Microsoft Graph Api.**

You can filter the users based on **`createdDateTime`** property within a specific timeline.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the below results:***

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=createdDateTime ge 2022-01-01T00:00:00Z &$select=displayName,createdDateTime,id
```

[image]

**Alternatively**, you can make use of **`lastSignInDateTime`** from which you can retrieve the list of last signed-in users in specific time range.

In order to fetch sign-in activity, make sure to have either Azure AD premium P1 or P2 license and **`AuditLog.Read.All`** permission.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/usersselect=signInActivity,displayName
```

[image]

**References:**

[Is it possible to query Azure Active Directory users based on last modified date? **solved by me**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71786185/is-it-possible-to-query-azure-active-directory-users-based-on-last-modified-date/71796439?noredirect=1#comment128744944_71796439)

[List users - Microsoft Graph beta | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#example-5-list-the-last-sign-in-time-of-users-in-a-specific-time-range)

Comment: thank you so much for your helps  Sridevi , i will check this and contact you in case of any further helps